# : Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i received this error while customer post update incident through website.
i debugging whole source but the issue not reproduced. Please help in Which case these type of issue raise?

File : SupportController.cs
Method : detailsupdate(string[] Response_Type, string incidentid, string type,IncidentInfo incidentinfo)
Exception Message : Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index
Inner Exception : 
Stack Trace : at System.Collections.ArrayList.get_Item(Int32 index) at System.Collections.Specialized.NameObjectCollectionBase.BaseGetKey(Int32 index) at Syncfusion.Website.MvcApplication.Controllers.SupportController.detailsupdate(String[] Response_Type, String incidentid, String type, IncidentInfo incidentinfo)

Answer (score 2):

**In General about this error:**
This happens when you refer to an "`item`" from "`itemcollection`" when the collection itself has no values.
First you should make sure the collection contains atleast 1 item for you to refer to.
**About the specific one you have got:**
By looking at the error it seems to me that "get_Item" is called but there is nothing to get.  (i.e. the collection is empty).  Ensure you have the items added by some means.

Hope this helps!